# vuejs2 app blank screen on ios 9 ipad

Tags: ipad, webpack, vuejs2, ios9

[image]

Only on iPad with ios 9, this happens
I am using vue2 with webpack 3.6

EDIT
Installing babel-polyfill didn't solve the problem

webpack.base.conf.js

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js'],
```

but same error raised

Comment: I get blank screen

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what research you've undertaken to solve the problem, you've already tried, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: There is nothing to try I have babel-polifill so my project should work on old browsers it is getting the same blank screen with different errors on old firefox and old chrome versions